# Access Row Data to Columns Based Off ID

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access database for employee training and there is a class that each employee is required to have twice a year.

The table for that class looks like this:

```
EmployeeID  ClassDate   ClassHours
1           1/1/2011        8
1           7/31/2011       7
2           2/1/2011        8
2           8/31/2011       7
3           3/1/2011        8
3           9/30/2011       7
```

I want the table to be formated like this:

```
EmployeeID  ClassDate_1 ClassHours_1    ClassDate_2 ClassHours_2
1           1/1/2011        8           7/31/2011       7
2           2/1/2011        8           8/31/2011       7   
3           3/1/2011        8           9/30/2011       7
```

How do I write a query to move the second class date and hour fields to the same row based off the EmployeeID?

I have researched through this site and all the possible solutions appear to be overly complicated for what I am trying to acheive.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't do a table that looks like that -- it violates the first rule of database normalization.  You could keep a table of employees and a table of classes and write a query that gives you the desired results.

Comment: Hello maneesha. That is what I would like to do. Keep the original table as is but create a query that moves the fields common to the EmployeeID to the same row. I just don't know how to write the query to get that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a query with a sub-select

```
SELECT
    X.EmployeeID,
    X.d1 AS ClassDate_1, ec1.ClassHours AS ClassHours_1,
    X.d2 AS ClassDate_2, ec2.ClassHours AS ClassHours_2
FROM
    ( (SELECT e.EmployeeID, Min(e.ClassDate) AS d1, Max(e.ClassDate) AS d2
       FROM employee_classes AS e
       GROUP BY e.EmployeeID) AS X
      INNER JOIN employee_classes AS ec1
          ON X.EmployeeID = ec1.EmployeeID AND X.d1 = ec1.ClassDate
    )
    INNER JOIN employee_classes AS ec2
        ON X.EmployeeID = ec2.EmployeeID AND X.d2 = ec2.ClassDate;
```

---

Alternatively you could store the nested select as a query (let's call it `query1`):

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, Min(e.ClassDate) AS d1, Max(e.ClassDate) AS d2
FROM employee_classes AS e
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
```

and then use it in a second query

```
SELECT
    X.EmployeeID,
    X.d1 AS ClassDate_1, ec1.ClassHours AS ClassHours_1,
    X.d2 AS ClassDate_2, ec2.ClassHours AS ClassHours_2
FROM
    ( query1 AS X
      INNER JOIN employee_classes AS ec1
          ON X.EmployeeID = ec1.EmployeeID AND X.d1 = ec1.ClassDate
    )
    INNER JOIN employee_classes AS ec2
        ON X.EmployeeID = ec2.EmployeeID AND X.d2 = ec2.ClassDate;
```

---

It would be much easier if the hours were not displayed

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, Min(e.ClassDate) AS ClassDate_1, Max(e.ClassDate) AS ClassDate_2
FROM employee_classes AS e
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
```

---

Indeed there is a simpler solution, however it assumes that the table is sorted by `EmployeeID` and `ClassDate`. This assumption is not safe, as no natural sort order is guaranteed. Access can "decide" to reorganize the records in a different way at any time.

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    First(ClassDate) AS ClassDate_1, First(ClassHours) AS ClassHours_1,
    Last(ClassDate) AS ClassDate_2,  Last(ClassHours) AS ClassHours_2
FROM
    employee_classes
GROUP BY
   EmployeeID
ORDER BY
   EmployeeID;
```

Here again a sub-select can help

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    First(ClassDate) AS ClassDate_1, First(ClassHours) AS ClassHours_1,
    Last(ClassDate) AS ClassDate_2,  Last(ClassHours) AS ClassHours_2
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM employee_classes ORDER BY EmployeeID, ClassDate)
GROUP BY
   EmployeeID
ORDER BY
   EmployeeID;
```

Howsoever, either a sub-query or a second query is required.

Comment: Thank you very much Olivier. I used your first example and it worked well. However, sometimes a staff only took the course once and there is only one row entry. How do I implement a WHERE clause to check that ClassDate_2 <> ClassDate_1?

Comment: `IIf(X.d1 = X.d2, null, X.d2) AS ClassDate_2, IIf(ec1.ClassHours = ec2.ClassHours, null, ec2.ClassHours) AS ClassHours_2`.   However, the solution will only work for a maximum of two classes per employee. If you have more classes, you will have to use the solution of ChrisPadgham.

Comment: Olivier, thanks you so much for your help. This solution is working exactly as I need. I just had to change the second IIF statement to have the same expression as the first IIF statement. The ClassHours are always the same, so I changed it to check if the ClassDates are the same as the condition to get the hours. Again, thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you plan to do with the results if they are just for display here is a crosstab query that includes the ClassDate and Hours in the value cell (with the hours in brackets after the date)

```
TRANSFORM Last([ClassDate] & " (" & [ClassHours] & ")") AS Details
SELECT Classes.EmployeeId
FROM Classes
GROUP BY Classes.EmployeeId
PIVOT "Class " & (DCount("[ClassNumber]","[Classes]","[ClassDate]<#" & Format$([ClassDate],"dd-mmm-yyyy") & "# AND [EmployeeId]=" & [EmployeeId])+1);
```

this will allow for any number of classes, not just two per teacher.

[image: output from crosstab]
<sub>(source: [solsup.com.au](http://www.solsup.com.au/images/classes.jpg))</sub>