# Convert MS-Access Row Data to Columns based off ID

Tags: ms-access

I have a Table of Speakers that stores the data as such:

```
SessionID  ||  SpeakerID
1          ||  54
1          ||  897
2          ||  63
2          ||  897
2          ||  444
```

I'm trying to create a query that will display the data such that it returns 1 row per SessionID, with a column for each SpeakerID, like this:

```
SessionID  ||  SpeakerID 1 ||  SpeakerID 2 ||  SpeakerID 3
    1      ||  54          ||  897         ||
    2      ||  63          ||  897         || 444
```

I saw an old post that addressed this, and have been playing with it for quite awhile but can't make it work.
[Access Row Data to Columns Based Off ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989299/access-row-data-to-columns-based-off-id/8996669#8996669)
The results I'm getting look like this:

```
SessionID || SpeakerID 2 || SpeakerID 3
1         || 897         ||
2         ||             || 444
```

Can you tell me what I'm missing? Clearly it's skipping over some of my Speakers and only showing the last ones, but I'm not sure how to get the results I need. Removing  the "Last()" piece just throws an error.

```
TRANSFORM Last(SpeakersCustomerSort_qry.ID) AS SpeakerDetails
SELECT SpeakersCustomerSort_qry.SessionID
FROM SpeakersCustomerSort_qry
GROUP BY SpeakersCustomerSort_qry.SessionID
PIVOT "Speaker " & (DCount("[SessionID]","[SpeakersCustomerSort_qry]","SessionID=" & [SessionID])+1);
```

Comment: Would [this](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html) help you?

Answer (score 1):

If your table is named `Speakers`, then the SQL you are looking for is:

```
TRANSFORM Last(Speakers.SpeakerID) AS SpeakerDetails
SELECT Speakers.SessionID
FROM Speakers
GROUP BY Speakers.SessionID
PIVOT "Speaker " & (
  DCount("[SpeakerID]", 
         "[Speakers]", 
         "[SessionID] = " & [SessionID] & " AND [SpeakerID] < " & [SpeakerID]
  ) + 1
);
```

### How does this work?

#### Counting the Speakers

First, it might help to figure out what that `DCount` expression is doing. Try pasting this into the SQL view of a new query (again, for a table named `Speakers`):

```
SELECT Speakers.SessionID, Speakers.SpeakerID, 
  "Speaker " & (
    DCount("[SpeakerID]", 
           "[Speakers]", 
           "[SessionID] = " & [SessionID] & " AND [SpeakerID] < " & [SpeakerID]
  ) + 1) AS SpeakerNumber
FROM Speakers;
```

When you examine the results, you should see:

```
SessionID | SpeakerID | SpeakerNumber
--------- | --------- | -------------
        1 |        54 | Speaker 1
        1 |       897 | Speaker 2
        2 |        63 | Speaker 1
        2 |       897 | Speaker 3 
        2 |       444 | Speaker 2
```

The `SpeakerNumber` expression is performing the following calculation for each row in the `Speakers` table:

- Find all the rows in `Speakers` where `SessionID` matches the current SessionID...
- AND where `SpeakerID` is less than the current SpeakerID
- Count the values of `SpeakerID` in this set (= the number of rows)
- Add `1` to that count
- Prefix the result with `Speaker`

Let's try it for the first row in `Speakers`, where the current `SessionID` is `1` and the current `SpeakerID` is `54`:

- Find the set of rows where `SessionID = 1`:

  ```
  SessionID | SpeakerID
  --------- | ---------
          1 |        54
          1 |       897
  ```
- Within these, find the set of rows where `SpeakerID < 54`: *No rows!*
- Count the rows in this set: `0`
- `0 + 1 = 1`
- Prefix: `Speaker 1`

I'll leave it to the reader to work through the algorithm for the rest of the rows in the table, but hopefully you can see now where those values in `SpeakerNumber` came from.

So what we have here is a method of **counting up the SpeakerIDs for each Session, in ascending order of SpeakerID**, starting our count at 1.

#### Back to the Crosstab

Imagine taking the 3-column result above and cross-tabulating it, with each value of `SpeakerNumber` as the column headings, each value of `SessionID` as the row headings, and some summary of the corresponding `SpeakerIDs` in each cell. This is what the crosstab SQL at the top does.

The last wrinkle is: how do we want to summarize the `SpeakerIDs` that correspond to each combination of `SpeakerNumber` and `SessionID`? That's where the `Last([SpeakerID])` aggregate function comes in. It simply says:

- For each combination of `SpeakerNumber` and `SessionID`...
- Find all the matching `SpeakerIDs`
- Return the last one in that list

Since each `SpeakerNumber`/`SessionID` combo only matches a single SpeakerID, this just gives us the value of the corresponding `SpeakerID`. In this case, using the `First()` aggregate function would give the same result.

You have to use *some* sort of aggregate function in a cross-tabulation, because there theoretically could be more than one matching value for each combination of factors (this is why Access threw an error when the `Last()` function was removed).